# boost::property_tree xml pretty printing, formatting

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm following the [Five Minute Tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html) and I get as output (unsurprisingly) the file `debug_settings_out.xml`.

But my problem is, that it isn't well formatted. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<debug><filename>debug.log</filename><level>2</level></debug>
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<debug>
    <filename>debug.log</filename>
    <level>2</level>
</debug>
```

because it should be also manually editable.
How can I achieve that?

I already found the [settings](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/xml_parser/read_xml_id954816.html) I can pass to the parser, but none of them gave me the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation of PropertyTree is pretty bad (I've recently started improving it). What you need to do is pass a correct xml_writer_settings object to write_xml.

https://github.com/boostorg/property_tree/blob/master/include/boost/property_tree/detail/xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp

```
write_xml(filename, tree, std::locale(),
          xml_writer_make_settings(' ', 4));
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain to me, or show me where it is explained, what the `(' ', 4)` does? And what other options do I have?

Comment: The first argument is the indentation character, and the only other sensible choice is '\t' for a tab. The second is how often to repeat that character for each indent. There are no other options.

Comment: In case anyone else ends up here, and cannot get it to work: when writing to a stream, instead of a file, there is no locale param. I.e. this works: `write_xml(std::cout, tree, xml_writer_make_settings(' ', 4));`

Comment: any chance you could write the compiler / linker settings for use of this xml_writer_make_settings ?? I keep getting was not declared in this scope - even though I have use of ptree else where in my code

Comment: If I don't pass a `<type>` template argument to xml_writer_make_settings, then the compile fails: `xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp:55:30: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Str'`

Comment: This is old, but in case anyone comes here looking for the solution, I found success by using the class created by xml_writer_make_settings directly, as 
write_xml(stream, tree, xml_parser::xml_writer_settings<std::string>(' ', 4)); 
The template type specifier appears to be necessary. (As does property_tree scoping.)